# Change image of detail button inside UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have this `UITableViewCell`:

[image: ‏]

And I want this as the result: (forgive me for the bad edit)

[image: ‏]

That means to basically change the `detail button`'s image to another image.

#### My current code for the cell

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("New", comment: "Add a new element")
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")

cell.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        
cell.imageView?.preferredSymbolConfiguration = .init(scale: UIImage.SymbolScale.large)
        
cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
cell.accessoryType = .detailButton
```

#### What I've tried

I put this after the code above. (It doesn't work)

```
        for (i, view) in cell.subviews.enumerated() {
            if view as? UIButton != nil {
                (cell.subviews[i] as! UIButton).setImage(UIImage(systemName: "clock"), for: .normal) // Never executes
            } else {
                for (i, view) in view.subviews.enumerated() {
                    if view as? UIButton != nil {
                        (cell.subviews[i] as! UIButton).setImage(UIImage(systemName: "clock"), for: .normal) // Never executes
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This code search for a `UIButton` in the cell's `subviews`, and if it finds one it change it's image. But it never finds a button!

### View Hierarchy

[image: ‏]

[image: ‏]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @zeytin answer, I made an `UITableViewCell` extension for easier use, while also improving margins:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
/// Set accessory image to any UIImage.
/// - Made by:
///  Ori HPT
/// - Parameters:
///   - image: The image to set.
///   - color: The tint color of the image.
///   - selector: The action of the accessory.
///   - target: The target of the action. (self)
func setAccessoryImage(to image: UIImage, color: UIColor, selector: Selector?, target: Any?) {
    self.accessoryType = .none

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    let size = self.textLabel?.font.pointSize ?? UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).pointSize
    button.setPreferredSymbolConfiguration(.init(pointSize: size, weight: .regular, scale: UIImage.SymbolScale.large), forImageIn: .normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    if selector != nil {
        button.addTarget(target, action: selector!, for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    button.tintColor = color
    self.accessoryView = button
}
}
```

Example for how to use it:

```
cell.setAccessoryImage(to: UIImage(systemName: "clock")!, color: .systemBlue, selector: #selector(historyPressed), target: self)
```

This is the final result, compared to the system's `.detailButton` accessory:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to a loop, just use cellForRow function and set accessorView property of the cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

   // Other code...

   cell.accessoryType = .none
        
   let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
   button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "clock"), for: .normal)
   button.setPreferredSymbolConfiguration(.init(scale: UIImage.SymbolScale.large), forImageIn: .normal)
   button.sizeToFit()
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(historyPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
   cell.accessoryView = button

   return cell
}

@objc func historyPressed() {
    print("History button pressed")
}
```